# why does using '<=' instead of '<' in the loop condition gives a segmentation fault [SIGSEGV]?

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I was solving a problem on codechef in the DECEMBER contest - https://www.codechef.com/DEC19B/problems/BINADD . Somewhere in the code I put this loop :

```
    for(i=0;i<=(pos.size()-2);i++)
    {
    if(pos[i]<0) 
        continue;
    else if(len<(pos[i]-pos[i+1])) 
        len=pos[i]-abs(pos[i+1]);
    }
```

Here pos is a vector declared as: 
`vector<int> pos;`

For these values the code shows a SIGSEGV :

> size of pos = 1 , pos[0]=0 , len=0

But if I replace `i<=(pos.size()-2)` with `i<(pos.size()-1)` in the loop there occurs **NO** SIGSEGV . Does anyone have an explanation

**NOTE :** 
1) Full code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void func()
{   
    int i=0,len=0,index=0;
    string a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;

    if(b=="0") {std::cout << 0 << std::endl;return;}
    else if(a=="0") {std::cout << 1 << std::endl;return;}
    int n1,n2;
    n1=a.length();
    n2=b.length();
    if(n1<n2)
    { 
        i=n2-n1;
        while(i--)
            a="0"+a;
    }
    else 
    {   
        i=n1-n2; 
        while(i--) 
            b="0"+b;
    }
    std::vector<int> pos;
    i=a.length();
    while(i--)
    {
        if(a[i]=='0'&&b[i]=='0')
            pos.push_back(-i);
        if(a[i]=='1'&&b[i]=='1')
            pos.push_back(i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=(pos.size()-2);i++)
    {
        if(pos[i]<0) 
            continue;
        else if(len<(pos[i]-pos[i+1])) 
                 len=pos[i]-abs(pos[i+1]);
    }
    if(pos[i]>=0)
        if(len<(pos[i]+1))
            len=pos[i]+1;

    std::cout << (len+1) << std::endl;
}
int main() {

    int t,n;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t--)
        func();

    return 0;
}
```

2) For the test case :

> 1 1 1

The above code shows **SIGSEGV** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, `size()` is of type `size_t` which is unsigned, so `size() - n` potentially underflows for all non-zero `n`.

Because of this underflow, the loop will execute at least once.

With `i` equal to zero and `pos.size()` equal to 1, the indexing of `pos[i+1]` is undefined behaviour which may segfault:

```
else if(len<(pos[i]-pos[i+1])) 
    len=pos[i]-abs(pos[i+1]);
```

`pos` is a vector so often there will be more allocated that the size, so it might not segfault until `i` grows to be equal to the initial allocation size of the vector; when this happens the indexing of `pos[i+1]` is off the end of the memory allocated for the vector.

It's also possible it doesn't even segfault then, but at the next page boundary - once you have undefined behaviour then it's hard to tell exactly when a program crashes without debugging it or adding trace output, and it really doesn't matter that much either, as you should correct the code instead.

Comment: thank you so much . Actually it was silly to ask in other people's answer's comments why would it SIGSEGV even when pos.size()-2 is a very large number . I should have realized that part myself

Answer (score 1):

If the size of `pos` is `1`, `pos.size()-2` is not equal to `-1`, it is the maximum value which a `size_t` (which is an unsigned type) can hold on your system. So the loop runs till `i` is a very very large number.

There is a define for the maximum number: `SIZE_MAX`. It is usually on modern 64bit systems `18446744073709551615`.

`for(i=0;i<=(pos.size()-2);i++)` is for `pos.size()==1` an endless loop, for `i == SIZE_MAX`, the condition is `SIZE_MAX<=SIZE_MAX`, which is true and then `i` wrap around to `0` and so it goes on.

You are invoking undefined behavior by accessing the `vector` out of bounds. Probably the compiler optimises this away and so you simply count to `SIZE_MAX` again and again.

Comment: thanks man .But then shouldn't TLE occur instead of SIGSEGV beacause of the time limit

Answer (score 0):

`size()` returns an unsigned `size_t`. When size is 1, size -2 is a negative number which wraps round to a large posisibe number. Your for loop therefore executes when it shouldn't.

Comment: i get your point .But the  loop running when it shouldn't  won't cause a SIGSEGV right ? It will just execute many times

Comment: Well it'll crash when i is more than size - 2 and it tries to access and element that doesn't exist in the vector